# Graduated from University; where to put my portfolio?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, first-job, portfolio

I wrote my exercises on university by computers. I studied mathematics, physics, and computer science.

Now I have many LaTeX files on my computer and a memory stick. Is it wise to show at least some of them like thesis on Internet if employers wants to see my ways to write solutions? Will GitHub be a suitable place for that?

I'm looking for a job on mathematics on industry but I'm interested also some mathematical related programming.

Comment: By Tex files you mean LaTex Files? What kind of jobs are you applying for (industry, etc.)?

Comment: @DarkCygnus Yes. I used LaTex.

Comment: Linkedin might be another place to put your papers - id suggest using PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I have many LaTeX-files on my computer and a memory stick. Is it wise to show at least some of them like thesis on Internet if employers wants to see my ways to write solutions?

If you are well-versed in writing LaTex files, consider including that or mentioning it on your Resume, pointing your level of knowledge and perhaps mention some example documents you've done.

Sending samples of those files with your applications is something I would not suggest, unless they ask you to see some of the LaTex files you've done.

You mention you are seeking job in the software industry. You also mentioned GitHub.

Yes, GitHub is a good place (repository) where you can put your code that you wish to show others. There you can put some sample software you've coded that you feel comfortable showing and link it to your other media, etc..

However, even though LaTex *is* a programming language, jobs in the software industry usually seek for other more General Purpose languages (like, Java, JavaScript, and others). So unless the jobs you seek require a strong knowledge of LaTex, **I would suggest you focus and show projects that use the languages required in each job you seek** (this implies that you have to tailor your Resume for each application for optimal results).